# Is it possible to view/edit SSRS datasets from sharepoint?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a bunch of **shared datasets** on my old report server and I want to copy them to a SharePoint Document Library. I'm running SSRS integrated mode in SharePoint 2013 and I've already created my document library and added these three Content Types **Report Builder Model**, **Report Builder Report** and **Report Data Source**.

I've created and deployed some reports using my Report Builder and all work perfectly.

Now, I would like to know if there is a way to view/edit a *SSRS Dataset* on SharePoint (*.rsd file extension). As I can see, SharePoint support data source files (.rsds) and report files (.rdl, .rdlx), it also has the **Report Builder Model** type. I'm not sure about that type yet, but I tried to create a new one and I saw that it is not a dataset file.

Currently, if I upload a dataset file on my document library, SharePoint does not recognize my file. Once I uploaded it, I had to choose a type for the file, but I didn't have any type that matches with a SSRS dataset.

Looking the Content Types available to choose, I chose for  **Report Builder Model**, just to try, because the other ones were not reasonable. Then, I realized that I could change the datasource using the option **Manage Data Sources**, but just that, I could not change the name or the SQL query of the dataset.

Maybe SharePoint does not provide viewer or editors for shared datasets so I would like to know if I have to develop some code out of the box or I don't have to do it because SharePoint support that file type.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

sharepoint support it, you need to add the content type to the library.

google "sharepoint ssrs tutorial"

here is one with screen: http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com/2011/02/create-ssrs-report-with-sharepoint-2010.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer @urlreader. Previously, I've been searching a lot as you said but I could not find anything related to datasets. Probably, my question was not clear enough. I've just updated my question to clarify.